# CKEDITOR -- use backspace to select and strike text

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

When a user deletes text, I want to cross it out by selecting it and adding css to hide or "strike" it. I have code like this:

```
$(this).keypress(function (e) 
{
  var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
  if(key == 8)//backspace
  {         
     e.preventDefault();

     //this selects the previous character -- not the CKEDITOR way so prob not x-platform        
     window.getSelection().modify('extend','backward','character');

     var trackstyle = new CKEDITOR.style( { element : 'del', attributes : { 'class': 'del-'+randnumber + ' del' , 'data-datetime' : trackmysqldatetime, 'id': 'id-'+randnumber } } );

    if(window.getSelection())
    {                   
       trackstyle.apply( editor[c].document ));//editor[c] is the current editor                
    }
} });
```

This works -- the backspace selects the previous character and applies the strike through STYLE. But then the selection seems to disappear and I don't know how to recover it. I believe I need to place to cursor outside the beginning of the DELETED element, and then select and delete again. (Since the text with the applied style is hidden, I don't think I want to select that text?) Hitting backspace again would then select the next previous character...

Answer (score 0):

In CKEDITOR itself some plugins are there. Try this http://ckeditor.com/addon/lite .  Go through full documentation, You will get some ideas.

Comment: Yes I know about LITE. It uses the NYTimes ICE library and both have several problems: LITE only works one 1 instance; the ICE library messes up iPhone autocorrect, etc. They also have a dependency on Rangy. So I'm trying to do it another way.